# Reading a duration over 24h from Excel using EPPlus

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I am trying to read the text value of a specific cell from excel. The value in question is a formula which sums up multiple cells.

[image: Duration]

What Ive tried so far:

```
worksheet.Cells["E42"].Style.Numberformat.Format  = "hh:mm"; //and [hh]:mm
result = worksheet.Cells["E42"].Text;
```

Converting the `worksheet.Cells["E42"].Value` to DateTime using FromAoDate doesnt work for me either.
The best result was 08:20 which is conveniently 24h less than the actual value.

EDIT:
Results from the suggestions

```
worksheet.Cells["E42"].Style.Numberformat.Format  = "[hh]:mm";
result = worksheet.Cells["E42"].Text; //returns "08"

worksheet.Cells["E42"].Style.Numberformat.Format  = "hh:mm";
result = worksheet.Cells["E42"].Text; //returns "08:20"

worksheet.Cells["E42"].Style.Numberformat.Format  = "hh:mm";
result = worksheet.Cells["E42"].Text;
result = TimeSpan.TryParse((string)result, out TimeSpan tres); //returns 08:20:00

worksheet.Cells["E42"].Style.Numberformat.Format  = "[hh]:mm";
result = worksheet.Cells["E42"].Text;
result = TimeSpan.TryParse((string)result, out TimeSpan tres); //returns 8.00:00:00

//converting to DateTime has similar results

result = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(worksheet.Cells["E42"].Value)); 
//returns 31.12.1899 08:20:00
```

Comment: `[hh]:mm` is the correct number format to display hours > 23:59:59 (aka >=1).

Comment: I'm not sure if you have shown what you have tried to convert the value to a timespan grater htan 24h. just see that you appy a format and read a Text. What did `DateTime.FromAoDate(worksheet.Cells["E42"].Value)` return? For sure not `08:20` because a `DateTime` contains also a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent found a proper solution yet, but there is a way.

```cs
var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[2];
var value = worksheet.Cells["E42"].GetValue<DateTime>(); //the cell contains 32:20 in excel
//returns 31.12.1899 08:20:00
var value2 = worksheet.Cells["E39"].GetValue<DateTime>(); //the cell contains 00:00 in excel
// which returns 30.12.1899 00:00:00
var t = value.Subtract(value2); //returns 1.08:20:00, which translates to 32:20:00
```

The `00:00` Date seems to convert to `DateTime.Parse("30.12.1899 00:00:00");`
and `33:20` to `31.12.1899 08:20:00`, so by subtracting we can recover the actual timespan.

Here's an example implementation:

```cs
//Only works for single values
private bool TryGetTimeSpan(ExcelWorksheet sheet, string address, out TimeSpan? result)
{
    var excelMinDate = DateTime.Parse("30.12.1899 00:00:00");

    try
    {
        var time = sheet.Cells[address].GetValue<DateTime>();
        result = time.Subtract(excelMinDate);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        result = null;
        
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the time? why not keep it as a string?

Comment: @Matt It doesnt return the correct string, when the duration is over 24h, which was the initial problem. See the results in my edit

Comment: @Matt its working as intended, you can update your answer anyway if you have a cleaner solution. But `Cell.Text` did not work for me at all as it only returns "08" for my example.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a TimeSpan object that should work for your needs.

```
string result = worksheet.Cells["E42"].Text;
TimeSpan timeResult;

string[] split = result.Split(':');
timeResult = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(split[0]), int.Parse(split[1]), 0);
```